# sudo: aptitude: command not found

Tags: downloads, aptitude

Just reinstalled 14.*LTS on new HD. But when I try to load Bonic I get this error reply

```
rollo@rollo-desktop:~$ sudo aptitude install boinc-client boinc-manager
sudo: aptitude: command not found
rollo@rollo-desktop:~$
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`aptitude` is not included in Ubuntu installations by default; you have to install it to use it, typically, as `apt-get` is usually the way to install things.

You can install `aptitude` by running: `sudo apt-get install aptitude`